# How is the string sort optimised in CPython?

Tags: python, cpython

I have this code that is intentionally not performant:

```
def suffix_array_alternative_naive(s):
    return [rank for suffix, rank in sorted((s[i:], i) for i in range(len(s)))]

from random import randint

constant_string = lambda length: 'a' * length
random_string = lambda length: ''.join(chr(randint(0, 255)) for _ in range(length))

length = 10000
s1 = constant_string(length)
s2 = random_string(length)

from time import time

for s in [s1, s2]:
    d = time()
    for _ in range(10):
        suffix_array_alternative_naive(s)
    print(time()-d)
```

- With pypy3:

  `2.0367980003356934
  1.9366297721862793`
- With python3:

  `0.48073387145996094
  0.5416769981384277`

  If I try with length = 100000 and one loop:
- pypy3:

  `48.4867467880249
  35.002175092697144`
- Python3

  `4.402702808380127
  4.469300031661987`

Normally the constant strings should be longer to compare between themselves because you have to read them entirely whereas the random strings should easily avoid the collisions between suffixes prefixes. Hence, the result of pypy3 is logical.

Why doesn't it work like that in CPython?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your “constant” strings are smaller than the random strings, due to the internal format of strings in Python.

```
>>> sys.getsizeof('\x7f')
50
>>> sys.getsizeof('\x80')
74
```

CPython uses an optimization which stores ASCII strings more compactly than non-ASCII strings.  To avoid this difference, use `randint(0, 127)`, which will generate ASCII-only constant strings.  Or use a non-ASCII character instead of `'a'`.

On top of that, the constant strings are already sorted. CPython's sort algorithm is Timsort, which is famous for being optimized for certain cases, like sorted or reverse-sorted inputs.

```
import random
import timeit

def constant_string(length):
    return 'a' * length
def random_string(length):
    return ''.join(chr(random.randint(0, 127)) for _ in range(length))

length = 10000
s1 = constant_string(length)
s2 = random_string(length)

for s in [s1, s2]:
    def test():
        arr = [s[i:] for i in range(len(s))]
        random.shuffle(arr)
        arr.sort()
    print(timeit.timeit(test, number=100))
```

On my computer, the constant string test takes about twice as long, now that both versions are sorting shuffled arrays containing values of the same size.

Comment: Interesting, thanks! However, with the original code and randint(ord('a'), ord('z')), I have similar results (a bit faster for CPython).

Comment: @Labo: The "constant" strings are already sorted. Sorting an array is pretty fast if it's sorted to begin with.

Comment: Thanks you! That's funny because theoretically in my example you trade the $log(n)$ factor of the sort for the $n$ factor of comparison…

Comment: For random strings, comparison is log N, sorting uses N log N comparisons, so the time should be N log N log N. For constant strings, comparison is N, but sorted strings require N comparisons, so it comes out to N^2, or N^2 log N for shuffled constant strings. In all cases, the random strings will be the fastest asymptotically.

Comment: That comparison time for random strings should be O(1), not O(log N).

Comment: Yes, that's exactly why I found it strange :) Thanks for your explanations!